# "This page isn’t working "domain name" is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" when I try to upload 30MB file

Tags: php, laravel

This only happens when I try to upload a big PNG image file. In my php.ini file I have set this:

```
post_max_size = 225M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

This allowed me to upload images with big size but I still can't upload this 30MB image. Any tips?

Comment: max_execution_time timeouts?

Comment: max_execution_time is 30

Comment: increase to 3000 and retest, check php error log by the way

Comment: Still getting HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: What is in error log?